# Debian 9 does not boot after installing on USB drive with UEFI

Tags: debian, boot, live-usb

## Goal: boot up from fully installed debian 9 USB drive

I installed debian into my USB drive but it **fails to recognize my USB in boot option**.
This is the [link](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/bt-hybrid/) where I downloaded the iso file.

### Below are what I have tried

1. I tried to burn the iso into my first USB drive using **Rufus**
2. I then try to boot from the **USB live**
3. I run through the setup progress, burning the OS into my **second USB**. During the progress, it did not show any errors. (it was able to detect my second USB).
4. However, after I finished the setup. It did not show up **the second USB** as one of the boot option.

I checked the boot sequence. My first priority is USB port. 
I repeated all the steps mentioned above on my friend laptop (Windows 10) and it worked on his laptop.

**Update:**

1) I unplugged the internal hard drive and setting up debian without it, it just tells me no bootable drive.

2) Run the checksum

```
C:\Users\PC\Downloads\ISO>certutil -hashfile debian-live-9.8.0-amd64-gnome+nonfree.iso MD5
MD5 hash of debian-live-9.8.0-amd64-gnome+nonfree.iso:
83436d6e797c75084dbeba203f5a818d
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
```

it is the same as the official website.

3) I tried to copy the **ESI files**`/EFI/boot` and `/EFI/debian` from Windows and pasted it to the **USB ESI partition**

4) I also took out my second internal Hard Drive and inserted a new Hard drive to install Debian into it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Here is how I fixed it

This is how the files in the USB ESP partition should look like:

```
full-install USB  
  ESP partition  
    EFI  (directory)  
     Boot  (directory)  
       bootx64.efi
       grubx64.efi
       fbx64.efi
     debian  (directory)  
       grubx64.efi
```

However there were **NO EFI FILES** in my USB after I finished installing (So please check your ESP partition!). So I have to copy the `Boot` folder and `debian` folder from **Windows ESP parition** and copy the `grubx64.efi` into `Boot` folder

---

- Details about how to access EFI partition in Windows please check out [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/662823/how-do-i-mount-the-efi-partition-on-windows-8-1-so-that-it-is-readable-and-write)
- Details about how to access EFI partition in USB please check out [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126674/boot-option-not-included-usb-after-fully-installed-in-usb-with-uefi)

**NOTE:** to access the EFI partition in USB you have to use any Linux distros live USB and I was using Kali live USB.

Answer (score 2):

Fix working for my laptop with weak EFI implementation only recognizes the fallback bootloader (found at https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall, where it is explained in more detail how to do this with LiveCD rescue mode):

```
mkdir /boot/efi/EFI/boot
cp /boot/efi/EFI/debian/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi
```